# Android Nav Drawer crashes somewhat frequently, stack doesn't reference my app at all

Tags: android

I'm using Android's "official" sliding drawer for navigation, classes like this:

`android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout`

and such.

Since implementing it into my app, I've seen a new bug which gets reported somewhat frequently:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at android.support.v4.widget.ViewDragHelper.continueSettling(ViewDragHelper.java:719)
   at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.computeScroll(DrawerLayout.java:764)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13398)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3214)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3084)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13717)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12665)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12709)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13438)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3214)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3084)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12663)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12709)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13438)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3214)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3084)
   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13717)
   at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2458)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12665)
   at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12709)
   at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1168)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2160)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2032)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1843)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1005)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4243)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4777)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:998)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:765)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

As you can see, the crash has nothing to do my app at all, at least in the stack trace, though I imagine there is something I can do to prevent it from happening.

I looked around online and found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60671

The person found the problem to be caused by using the ViewDragHelper class, which I am not using at all in my app. The only thing I really do directly to the drawer besides initializing it is force-closing occasionally, but I doubt that's what is going on here.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: possibly related google code issue : [60464 - DrawerLayout throwing ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any update on this?
I was having the same issue, and i fixed it by overriding onDrawerStateChanged on  ActionBarDrawerToggle, i keep the current state of the drawer and only allow closing/oppening the drawer when the drawer state is idle.

```
@Override
public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {
      drawable_state = newState;
      super.onDrawerStateChanged(newState);

}
```

And when trying to close/open the drawer

```
if(drawable_state == DrawerLayout.STATE_IDLE){
      toggle();
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes. I've never been able to recreate it myself, but next time I push a release I should be able to quickly see if it's working or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that happens when you attempt to change your `DrawerLayout` within the `ActionBarDrawerToggle`. To fix this, you need to post the code you are attempting to run to the end of the View's runnable queue, which looks something like this:

```
mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //your code
    }
};
```